# how to add a new record to a Many To Many Field

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a small project using Django / Rest Framework, I have two models ( Contact & List )
I have Many To Many field, in Contact called list.

I would like to know how can I add a record to this relation ( Many To Many Field ).

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class List(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=255)
    comment = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=255)
    private = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    allowed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**This is my Contact Model**

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from list.models import List


# Create your models here.

class Contact(models.Model):
    # field variables 
    language_choices = (
        ('french', 'french'),
        ('english', 'english'),
    )

    
    """ Relations Between Models """
    list = models.ManyToManyField(List)
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Answer (score 0):

I looked for a solution for a long time.
Here is my method.

models.py

```
class Candidate(models.Model):
    skills = models.ManyToManyField(Skill, through='SkillExperience')

class SkillExperience(models.Model):
    """Skills and experiences for a candidate"""
    skill = models.ForeignKey(Skill, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='skill_to_candidate')
    candidate = models.ForeignKey(Candidate, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='candidate_to_skill')
    experience = models.ForeignKey(Experience, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='experience_to_candidate', default=1)
```

serializer.py

```
class CandidateSkillExperienceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    experience = ExperienceSerializer(many=False, allow_null=True)
    skill = SkillSerializerLite(many=False, allow_null=False)

    class Meta:
        model = SkillExperience
        fields = ('skill', 'experience')


class CandidateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    candidate_to_skill = CandidateSkillExperienceSerializer(many=True, required=False, allow_null=True)
```